# How do I get the annotated class from a Condition

Tags: java, spring

I have implemented a *Condition* that checks if the *AnnotatedTypeMetadata* supplied in *matches* is an instance of *AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor* and then checks if cron.[className.makePretty()] is set in config. This has allowed me to do stuff like:

```
@Condition(TaskConditional.class)
public class DoImportantStuffTask {
  @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.do-important-stuff}")
  public void run() {
  ...
```

and have that only be instanciated when 'cron.do-important-stuff' is set in config. The condition also checks if cron.enabled is true and if cron.host is set and equal to current hostname.

The documentation for Spring 5.2 states:

> As of Spring Framework 5.2, this class has been replaced by SimpleAnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor for internal use within the framework, but there is no public replacement for AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor

Is there a way to still get the name of the annotated class (DoImportantStuffTask.class) in my condition's match method with Spring 5.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You now can get the source of the annotations with *getAnnotations()* in *AnnotatedTypeMetadata*. And thus to get the class name I did

```
String annotatedClasss = md.getAnnotations().stream()
    .map(a -> a.getSource().toString())
    .distinct()
    .findAny();
```